# Footer with scrpage2 - footline crosses foot

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I'm switching from `fancyhdr` to `scrpage2` right now and nearly everything is working fine. There is just one problem. The footer i have to build is pretty big and the line which should seperate it from the text crosses the footer instead of being above of it. On the otherhand the headsepline works fine no matter how big the header is. The only way i found to get the line above the footer is to set options in the geometry package, but i don't think this should be the way to do this and it is not pretty comfortable and even less good looking.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\headheight}{18ex}
\automark{section}
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{ %
{} %
{} %
{\parbox{5cm}{logo \\ \medskip \hspace{0.15cm} www.awwwwr.com} \hfill \parbox{5cm}      {\raggedleft  Pages \\
Autor: \\
Date: \\
Bla \\
Date: \\
Date: \\
Date: \\}}
} 
{%
(\linewidth,1pt)
{} 
{}
{\scriptsize 
\begin{tabular}{l}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
\hfill 
\begin{tabular}{r}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
} 
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this in a good way with the `scrpage2` package or is there no option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines with changes are marked % PS. 
Only the position of tables have been corected.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\headheight}{18ex}
\automark{section}
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{ %
{} %
{} %
{\parbox{5cm}{logo \\ \medskip \hspace{0.15cm} www.awwwwr.com} \hfill \parbox{5cm}      {\raggedleft  Pages \\
Autor: \\
Date: \\
Bla \\
Date: \\
Date: \\
Date: \\}}
}
{%
(\linewidth,1pt)
{} 
{}
{\scriptsize 
%\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l} % PS
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
\hfill 
%\begin{tabular}{r}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l} % PS
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
} 
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`scrpage2` is obsolete. Since 2013 the official successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`. If I only replace `scrpage2` by `scrlayer-scrpage` in your example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\headheight}{18ex}
\automark{section}
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{ %
{} %
{} %
{\parbox{5cm}{logo \\ \medskip \hspace{0.15cm} www.awwwwr.com} \hfill \parbox{5cm}      {\raggedleft  Pages \\
Autor: \\
Date: \\
Bla \\
Date: \\
Date: \\
Date: \\}}
} 
{%
(\linewidth,1pt)
{} 
{}
{\scriptsize 
\begin{tabular}{l}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
\hfill 
\begin{tabular}{r}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
} 
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I get the result:

[image]

But I also get warning messages:

> ```
> Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 89.08252pt needed,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 84.86224pt found.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \headheight, for further
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `headheight=89.08252pt'.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also decrease \topmargin on input line 45.
>
> Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \footheight to low.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 56.99991pt needed,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 17.0pt found.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \footheight, for further
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `footheight=56.99991pt'.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also increase \footskip on input line 45.
> ```

So perhaps even something like:

```
\documentclass[oneside,headinclude,footheight=57pt,headheight=89.1pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\automark{section}
\defpagestyle{mystyle}{ %
{} %
{} %
{\parbox{5cm}{logo \\ \medskip \hspace{0.15cm} www.awwwwr.com} \hfill \parbox{5cm}      {\raggedleft  Pages \\
Autor: \\
Date: \\
Bla \\
Date: \\
Date: \\
Date: \\}}
} 
{%
(\linewidth,1pt)
{} 
{}
{\scriptsize 
\begin{tabular}{l}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
\hfill 
\begin{tabular}{r}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6
\end{tabular}
} 
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\section{bla}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

would be better.